# Machine Learning Model Choice: Use Features to Predict the Order/Schedule of Labels

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, machine-learning-model

The question is, now we have a list of items, and for each item, we have its features (multi-dimensional) and an order/schedule of labels (of another category of item, and we only know the labels instead of detailed information). Then can we learn from this to predict the order of labels if given an item and its features?

For example:
We have *item_1* and its features: {feature_11, feature_12, feature_13 ...} and an order {l1, l2, l3 ...}. Then given *item2* and its features {feature_21, feature_22, feature_23 ...}, could we predict the order of labels for *item2*?

Comment: What do you mean by order? Is it a constant size vector??

Comment: Yes, and the index in the vector means priority

Comment: you can have a look at `sequence to sequence prediction`. Using recurrent neural networks you should be able to generate a sequence. It will be very difficult to share a concrete model as the problem statement is still very ambigous.